# how to display values from dictionary which contains list as value in django

Tags: python, django

i want to display records form dictionary which contains list as value in table format.

my dictionary looks like this and i am passing this dictionary through view.py file as {'data':datas}

```
enroll_number=[1,2,3]
names = ['tom','mike','john']
total = [80,90,80]

datas={
'id':enroll_number,
'names':names,
'total':avgs,
}
```

in my HTML page my code is something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr class="text-center">
    <th scope="col">Id</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Total</th>
</tr>
{% for key, value_list  in datas.items %}
<tr>
    {% for value in value_list %}
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

so i am getting output like this:

```
Id Name Total
1 2 3 
tom mike john 
80 90 80
```

But i want output like this

```
Id Name Total
1  tom   80
2  mike  90
3  john  80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to zip them in your view and iterate through the joined list.

```
data = zip(enroll_number, names, avgs)
```

...

```
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    {% for item in row %}
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think that's the only proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your table data to be rows-oriented instead of columns-oriented:

```
In [2]: [dict(zip(['id', 'names', 'total'], x)) for x in zip(enroll_number, names, total)]
Out[2]:
[{'id': 1, 'names': 'tom', 'total': 80},
 {'id': 2, 'names': 'mike', 'total': 90},
 {'id': 3, 'names': 'john', 'total': 80}]
```

And then iterate over rows in your template.